# How to declare a public value (val) in a Kotlin class to initialize it later. Cannot use var in this particular case

Tags: android, variables, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to make a simple camera app on Android Using Kotlin. I'm not able to convert some java code into Kotlin.
How do I declare **cameraDevice** in Kotlin?

Java Code:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            cameraDevice = camera;
            randomFunction();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
             cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
}
```

Kotlin Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    val cameraDevice:CameraDevice?;
    private val stateCallback: CameraDevice.StateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            cameraDevice = camera;
            randomFunction();
        }
        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error:Int) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
}
```

I'm not able to define it as a var, it is throwing *Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type CameraDevice?*
and I'm not able to declare it in the function, throws the same error.

Comment: Use `var cameraDevice:CameraDevice? = null` and use it like `cameraDevice?.close()`. If you use **val** then you can't reassign it like `cameraDevice = camera`

Comment: Can you explain why not you want to declare it as `var`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `lateinit` for `cameraDevice` like this:

```
lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice
```

If you run into `onError`, you check whether `cameraDevice` has been initialized and only then invoke `close()` it to avoid getting an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.

```
@Override
public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
    if(::cameraDevice.isInitialized) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**cameraDevice** can be null anytime. So you will have to assert not null in order to execute your code. But make sure cameraDevice is never null here.
So, use your code as below

```
@Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            cameraDevice!! = camera;
            randomFunction();
        }
```

Use this everywhere in your code.

Comment: this doesn't really tell OP how to initialize it where they declare it

Comment: you're missing the `val cameraDevice:CameraDevice? = null`

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing this

```
     val cameraDevice:CameraDevice?;
```

`val` variable need initial `initialization` mean you have assign value at declaration 
 and after `initialization` of variable you cannot change the value of it.

If you want to late initialize then you can do this way

```
  var  cameraDevice:CameraDevice?=null // you have to assign the null at initial
```

OR you can use `lateinit` just like this

```
  lateinit var cameraDevice:CameraDevice  //this does not required initialization at initial level
```

Comment: i also thought of `lateinit`, but that only works if the variable WAS initialized in `onOpened`. if it only goes into `onError`, it will crash.